# CMake cross-compiling: how to link libraries depending on target architecture

Tags: build, cmake, cross-compiling

I am new to cmake. I want to build my project for x86 and arm architectures (on x64 machine). I setup two toolchain files: **x86.cmake** and **arm.cmake**, with paths to compilers.
My project uses my own pre-compiled libraries which lay in different paths for x86 and arm. So the question is how do I link these libraries depending on target architecture?

The way I see now is set `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)` in **arm.cmake** toolchain and 
`set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86)` for **x86.cmake** toolchain and then depending on this variable choose the right paths of libraries.

Is this the right way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake: Link precompiled library depending on OS and architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126860/cmake-link-precompiled-library-depending-on-os-and-architecture)

Answer (score 0):

Usually libraries needed for link with are searched with [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/find_library.html) command. This command uses several hints which could be set in the toolchain file. E.g.:

- [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) variable
- [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.html) variable

So, result of `find_library` could be different for different toolchains in use.

Comment: What if my libraries are in the same directory but have different name, e.g.: mylib_x86.so and mylib_arm.so?

Comment: In that case you need to check `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` variable as described in the second paragraph of your question post.